# How to write an ARRAY into SNOWFLAKE database using python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am fetching data from tiktok API -> https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/adgroup/get/
that I need to write in Snowflake Database.

Data is like as below ->

```
{
   "adgroup_app_profile_page_state":null,
   "adgroup_id":"AD_GROUP_ID",
   "adgroup_name":"AUTO_PR_C",
   "advertiser_id":"ADVERTISIER_ID",
   "age_groups":[
      "AGE_18_24",
      "AGE_25_34",
      "AGE_35_44",
      "AGE_45_54",
      "AGE_55_100"
   ]
}
```

**How do I write this age_group ARRAY into snowflake table column?**

I have tried like this ->

```
if ad_group_data and 'list' in ad_group_data['data']:
        ad_group_list = ad_group_data['data']['list']
        
        adGroup_table = 'ADGROUP'
        adGroup_insert_query = f'''
        INSERT INTO {adGroup_table} (
        adgroup_app_profile_page_state, adgroup_id, adgroup_name, advertiser_id, age_groups

        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        '''
        adGroup_data_to_insert = []
        for ad_group in ad_group_list:
            adgroup_app_profile_page_state = ad_group.get('adgroup_app_profile_page_state') if 'adgroup_app_profile_page_state' in ad_group else None
            adgroup_id = ad_group.get('adgroup_id') if 'adgroup_id' in ad_group else None
            adgroup_name = ad_group.get('adgroup_name') if 'adgroup_name' in ad_group else None
            advertiser_id = ad_group.get('advertiser_id') if 'advertiser_id' in ad_group else None
            age_groups = ad_group['age_groups'][0] if ad_group['age_groups'] else None
          
            adgroup_data_tuple = (
                adgroup_app_profile_page_state,
                adgroup_id,
                adgroup_name,
                advertiser_id,
                age_groups
                )
            adGroup_data_to_insert.append(adgroup_data_tuple)
            cursor.executemany(adGroup_insert_query, adGroup_data_to_insert)
            conn.commit()
```

**But this way only first value of the array gets stored, I have also tried to define age_group column as VARIENT in snowflake, but that also doesn't work**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine

```
INSERT INTO {table_name} (
        adgroup_app_profile_page_state, adgroup_id, adgroup_name, advertiser_id,
        age_groups)
        SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(%s);
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use pair: `json.dumps` and `PARSE_JSON`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(arr ARRAY);
```

Python code:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import json

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    age_groups = [1,2,3,4]
    session.sql('INSERT INTO tab(arr) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?)',
                params = [json.dumps(age_groups)]).collect()
    return 'Success'
```

Check:

```
SELECT * FROM tab;
-- arr
-- [   1,   2,   3,   4 ]
```

Comment: This does not help, I have to enter data in this way -> VALUES ('app_profile', 'adGroup_id', 'AUTO_PR_C', 'advertisier_ID', '[
      "AGE_18_24",
      "AGE_25_34",
      "AGE_35_44",
      "AGE_45_54",
      "AGE_55_100"
   ]') -> Only one column would be accepting ARRY, others will have STRING values

Comment: @gourav "Only one column would be accepting ARRY, others will have STRING values" Where is the issue? Simply adding other columns - `INSERT INTO tab(col1, col2, arr) SELECT ?, ?, PARSE_JSON(?)'`